Letting Part act on a list while holding the elements inside
I'm using
f[functions___] := {
  Do[{
     func = Extract[{functions}, {i}, HoldComplete], 
   (*other stuff here*)
    Print[func]},
 {i, Length[{functions}]
}]}

I need to do some other things where the comment is, using the expressions in functions
But we can see that if I try
f[Array[# &, 5], Array[# &, 10]] The print returns the arrays rather than the expressions. When I try doing my other things in the comment section, it is also clear to me that the expression has already been evaluated.

This is what Extract is for. Extract[expr, pos, HoldComplete] will take a part from an expression and wrap HoldComplete around it to keep it inert.

Use 3-argument Extract:
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll];
expr = f[Array[# &, 5], Array[# &, 10]];

Extract[expr, {1}, Hold]


Hold[Array[#1 &, 5]]

Edit
The question was updated with this code:
f[functions___] := {
  Do[{
     func = Extract[{functions}, {i}, HoldComplete], 
   (*other stuff here*)
    Print[func]},
 {i, Length[{functions}]
}]}

First of all: you need SetAttributes[f, HoldAll], otherwise functions will evaluate before the internal code ever sees them.
The reason Extract doesn't work here, is because you inserted functions into a List, which is not a holding wrapper. That's where the evaluation takes place. This should work:
SetAttributes[f, HoldAllComplete];
f[functions___] := (
 Do[
   (
     func = Extract[HoldComplete[functions], {i}, HoldComplete]; 
     (*other stuff here*)
     Print[func]
   ),
   {i, Length[HoldComplete[functions]]}
 ]
);

Note also that I replaced some of the misused cases of List.
In general: if you want to hold expressions unevaluated, you need to be really careful. In your case it's honestly easier to just remove all of the holding and just call your function with HoldComplete around the individual arguments:
ff[functions___] := (
   Do[
    (
     func = Extract[{functions}, {i}];
     (*other stuff here*)
     Print[func]
     ),
    {i, Length[{functions}]}
    ]
   );

You can then simply replace f with a definition that wraps all expressions in HoldComplete and passes it to ff:
ClearAll[f];
SetAttributes[f, HoldAllComplete];
f[functions___] := ff @@ Map[HoldComplete, HoldComplete[functions]]


I tried just your code in isolation, and it seemed to work, but once in my function it didn't seem to work.

I see you updated your question. I'll update this answer as well

There are a couple of preliminaries to deal with, which may have more to do with you just leaving out detail than with any actual errors. Let's start with this:
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll];
f[x___] := DoSomethingToFirstArg[x[[1]]];
f[Array[# &, 5], Array[# &, 10]]

This won't do what most people expect, and it's because x is a sequence and so x[[1]] is a problem. So, when you say you call x[[1]], you actually need to call {x}[[1]]. Let's make that change.
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll];
f[x___] := DoSomethingToFirstArg[{x}[[1]]];
f[Array[# &, 5], Array[# &, 10]]
(* DoSomethingToFirstArg[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}] *)

Okay, now we can address your actual question. But it's a bit ambiguous. There's manipulating x within the body of f and there's returning something from f that depends on x. In the former situation, we typically use Unevaluated. In the latter we use some type of Hold*.
So, let's change the definition of f to extract the head of the first argument in the argument sequence x.
f[x___] := Unevaluated[{x}][[1, 0]];(* Wrapping x in List isn't strictly necessary in this case, but let's not digress. *)
f[Array[# &, 5], Array[# &, 10]]
(* Array *)

It was Array, not List, so this worked. But, Unevaluated is only temporary. As soon as you do something to the Unevaluated expression, the Unevaluated is "stripped" and normal evaluation continues. In this case, Array evaluates to Array, so no problem. But, if you want to return something and keep it from evaluating, you'll need to apply one of the Hold* heads. Let's just use Hold itself.
f[x___] := First[Hold /@ Unevaluated[{x}]];
f[Array[# &, 5], Array[# &, 10]]
(* Hold[Array[#1 &, 5]] *)

